# Merging entries and calculating their average in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 2 columns: One representing a date and the other represents a rate that was give in that day. Some days appear more than once and what I would like to do is to caculate the average of the rates given in that day and leave only one entry with that date and with the average rate. Something like that:

From this:

```
dat = data.frame(date = c(10, 10, 20), rate = c(4, 2, 1))
dat
  date rate
1   10    4
2   10    2
3   20    1
```

To this:

```
  date rate
1   10    3
2   20    1
```

How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
aggregate(rate~date,dat,mean)
```